# Is there any API to get the possible values accepted by VideoDeviceController.GetDeviceProperty on a Windows Store App?

Tags: camera, windows-store-apps

Is there any API to get the possible values accepted by [VideoDeviceController.GetDeviceProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/apps/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.getdeviceproperty) on a Windows Store App?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I believe not. [Justin Angel's analysis of a pre-release leak of Windows 8.1](http://justinangel.net/Win81APIs#minor) appears to imply that this may be added in the next update. Look under "Minor, but important" -> "Media".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found the answer, for example:

```
await _mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.IsoSpeedControl.SetPresetAsync(
    IsoSpeedPreset.Iso400);
```